# Sum quantity with same price, excel

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with a quantity in column a and a price in column b.

i want the sum of quantities at each price. The image is just a small piece. the list can get quite long. So at price 5665,5 the desired result would be 0 (-7+7+6-6+35-35)

[image]

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on ***Microsoft-365*** then could use

`D2` cell `=UNIQUE(B2:B18)` 
`E2` cell `=SUMIFS(A2:A18,B2:B18,D2#)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about [Pivot Tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010089893.aspx#_Toc263767342).
Just follow Microsoft official tutorial it's easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Like @Harun24HR pointed out, if you’re using Microsoft 365, the **UNIQUE array function** comes handy. However, for desktop versions of Microsoft Office, you can use **PIVOT TABLE** or alternatively use the following:

**NOTE:** Ensure your data is in table format. **Sales** is the name of the table.

[image: See Table]

**Column A (Quantity):** Contains the given quantities

**Column B (Price):** The corresponding prices of the given quantities

**Column C (Rank):** Returns the ranks of the prices. In cell C2, enter the code:
`=RANK.EQ([@Price],[Price])`

**Column D (Remove Duplicates):** Removes duplicate and get unique ranks of prices. In cell D2, enter:
`=IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)=1,C2,"")`

**Column E (Ordering):** Order the unique ranks in either ascending or descending order. In cell E2, enter:
`=IFERROR(LARGE([REMOVE DUPLICATES],ROW()-ROW(Sales[[#Headers],[REMOVE DUPLICATES]])), "")`

**Column F (Unique Price):** Obtain the unique prices. In F2, enter:
`=IFNA(INDEX(Sales[[Price]:[RANK]], MATCH([@ORDERING], [RANK], 0), 1), "")`

**Column G (Sum of Qty):** In cell G2, enter:
`=IF([@[UNIQUE PRICE]]="", "", SUMIF([Price], [@[UNIQUE PRICE]], [Quantity]))`